# Configuring two server simultaneously at apache local

Tags: apache

I wanna configure two server simutaneoulsy at my apache. one is with name `localhost` n another is with name `shadaab`.

What I did was edited `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and added these lines at last of files

```
    NameVirtualHost localhost

    <VirtualHost localhost>
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        ServerName localhost 
    </VirtualHost> 


    NameVirtualHost shadaab

    <VirtualHost shadaab> 
        DocumentRoot "F:/projects/all/" 
        ServerName shadaab
    </VirtualHost>
```

Restarted apache server. When I browse in url `localhost` its working fine but when I did for 'shadaab' it doesn't work.

Later on how mysql will be connected with shadaab server pelase help. What other changes do I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is WAY off. I suggest [reading some documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Your config *should* look something like:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80> 
    DocumentRoot "F:/projects/all/" 
    ServerName shadaab
</VirtualHost>
```

Or replace `127.0.0.1` with `*` to make apache listen on all IP addresses, not just the loopback.

Comment: Do I need to do in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` file only. Correct ?? No mroe changes

Comment: @Sankalp Ideally, yes.

Comment: @Sankalp Check your logs, read docs, amend config, attempt restart, repeat until working. Welcome to Apache administration.

Comment: I have restarted (Logout and login again to my account.) Error log doesn't show anything regarding shadaab not even accesslog

Answer (score 1):

add

127.0.0.1 shadaab

in your host file

You will be able to connect to your mysql server via shadaab.
shadaab will point to 127.0.0.1

Comment: where is my host file. please specify name n location.? How my sql will be connected then with  localhost or shadaab or something else.

Comment: [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) lists the location of the hosts file for a whole slew of OS'es.